# Make the tabs active on scroll even after the Horizontal overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

  var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
  var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

  function myFunction() {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
      navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    }
     else {
      navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
  }
        var SETTINGS = {
            navBarTravelling: false,
            navBarTravelDirection: "",
            navBarTravelDistance: 150
        }

        var colours = {
            0: "#867100",
            1: "#7F4200",
            2: "#99813D",
            3: "#40FEFF",
            4: "#14CC99",
            5: "#00BAFF",
            6: "#0082B2",
            7: "#B25D7A",
            8: "#00FF17",
            9: "#006B49",
            10: "#00B27A",
            11: "#996B3D",
            12: "#CC7014",
            13: "#40FF8C",
            14: "#FF3400",
            15: "#ECBB5E",
            16: "#ECBB0C",
            17: "#B9D912",
            18: "#253A93",
            19: "#125FB9",
        }

        document.documentElement.classList.remove("no-js");
        document.documentElement.classList.add("js");

        // Out advancer buttons
        var pnAdvancerLeft = document.getElementById("pnAdvancerLeft");
        var pnAdvancerRight = document.getElementById("pnAdvancerRight");
        // the indicator
        var pnIndicator = document.getElementById("pnIndicator");

        var pnProductNav = document.getElementById("pnProductNav");
        var pnProductNavContents = document.getElementById("pnProductNavContents");

        pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));

        // Set the indicator
        moveIndicator(pnProductNav.querySelector("[aria-selected=\"true\"]"), colours[0]);

        // Handle the scroll of the horizontal container
        var last_known_scroll_position = 0;
        var ticking = false;

        function doSomething(scroll_pos) {
            pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));
        }

        pnProductNav.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
            last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;
            if (!ticking) {
                window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                    doSomething(last_known_scroll_position);
                    ticking = false;
                });
            }
            ticking = true;
        });


        pnAdvancerLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // If in the middle of a move return
            if (SETTINGS.navBarTravelling === true) {
                return;
            }
            // If we have content overflowing both sides or on the left
            if (determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "left" || determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "both") {
                // Find how far this panel has been scrolled
                var availableScrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft;
                // If the space available is less than two lots of our desired distance, just move the whole amount
                // otherwise, move by the amount in the settings
                if (availableScrollLeft < SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance * 2) {
                    pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(" + availableScrollLeft + "px)";
                } else {
                    pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(" + SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance + "px)";
                }
                // We do want a transition (this is set in CSS) when moving so remove the class that would prevent that
                pnProductNavContents.classList.remove("sticky-tabs-container-no-transition");
                // Update our settings
                SETTINGS.navBarTravelDirection = "left";
                SETTINGS.navBarTravelling = true;
            }
            // Now update the attribute in the DOM
            pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));
        });

        pnAdvancerRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
            // If in the middle of a move return
            if (SETTINGS.navBarTravelling === true) {
                return;
            }
            // If we have content overflowing both sides or on the right
            if (determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "right" || determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav) === "both") {
                // Get the right edge of the container and content
                var navBarRightEdge = pnProductNavContents.getBoundingClientRect().right;
                var navBarScrollerRightEdge = pnProductNav.getBoundingClientRect().right;
                // Now we know how much space we have available to scroll
                var availableScrollRight = Math.floor(navBarRightEdge - navBarScrollerRightEdge);
                // If the space available is less than two lots of our desired distance, just move the whole amount
                // otherwise, move by the amount in the settings
                if (availableScrollRight < SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance * 2) {
                    pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(-" + availableScrollRight + "px)";
                } else {
                    pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "translateX(-" + SETTINGS.navBarTravelDistance + "px)";
                }
                // We do want a transition (this is set in CSS) when moving so remove the class that would prevent that
                pnProductNavContents.classList.remove("sticky-tabs-container-no-transition");
                // Update our settings
                SETTINGS.navBarTravelDirection = "right";
                SETTINGS.navBarTravelling = true;
            }
            // Now update the attribute in the DOM
            pnProductNav.setAttribute("data-overflowing", determineOverflow(pnProductNavContents, pnProductNav));
        });

        pnProductNavContents.addEventListener(
            "transitionend",
            function() {
                // get the value of the transform, apply that to the current scroll position (so get the scroll pos first) and then remove the transform
                var styleOfTransform = window.getComputedStyle(pnProductNavContents, null);
                var tr = styleOfTransform.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") || styleOfTransform.getPropertyValue("transform");
                // If there is no transition we want to default to 0 and not null
                var amount = Math.abs(parseInt(tr.split(",")[4]) || 0);
                pnProductNavContents.style.transform = "none";
                pnProductNavContents.classList.add("sticky-tabs-container-no-transition");
                // Now lets set the scroll position
                if (SETTINGS.navBarTravelDirection === "left") {
                    pnProductNav.scrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft - amount;
                } else {
                    pnProductNav.scrollLeft = pnProductNav.scrollLeft + amount;
                }
                SETTINGS.navBarTravelling = false;
            },
            false
        );

        // Handle setting the currently active link
        pnProductNavContents.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var links = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".sticky-tabs"));
            links.forEach(function(item) {
                item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
            })
            e.target.setAttribute("aria-selected", "true");
            // Pass the clicked item and it's colour to the move indicator function
            moveIndicator(e.target, colours[links.indexOf(e.target)]);
        });

        // var count = 0;
        function moveIndicator(item, color) {
            var textPosition = item.getBoundingClientRect();
            var container = pnProductNavContents.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            var distance = textPosition.left - container;
             var scroll = pnProductNavContents.scrollLeft;
            pnIndicator.style.transform = "translateX(" + (distance + scroll) + "px) scaleX(" + textPosition.width * 0.01 + ")";
            // count = count += 100;
            // pnIndicator.style.transform = "translateX(" + count + "px)";
            
            if (color) {
                pnIndicator.style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
        }

        function determineOverflow(content, container) {
            var containerMetrics = container.getBoundingClientRect();
            var containerMetricsRight = Math.floor(containerMetrics.right);
            var containerMetricsLeft = Math.floor(containerMetrics.left);
            var contentMetrics = content.getBoundingClientRect();
            var contentMetricsRight = Math.floor(contentMetrics.right);
            var contentMetricsLeft = Math.floor(contentMetrics.left);
             if (containerMetricsLeft > contentMetricsLeft && containerMetricsRight < contentMetricsRight) {
                return "both";
            } else if (contentMetricsLeft < containerMetricsLeft) {
                return "left";
            } else if (contentMetricsRight > containerMetricsRight) {
                return "right";
            } else {
                return "none";
            }
        }

        /**
         * @fileoverview dragscroll - scroll area by dragging
         * @version 0.0.8
         * 
         * @license MIT, see http://github.com/asvd/dragscroll
         * @copyright 2015 asvd <heliosframework@gmail.com> 
         */


        (function (root, factory) {
            if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
                define(['exports'], factory);
            } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
                factory(exports);
            } else {
                factory((root.dragscroll = {}));
            }
        }(this, function (exports) {
            var _window = window;
            var _document = document;
            var mousemove = 'mousemove';
            var mouseup = 'mouseup';
            var mousedown = 'mousedown';
            var EventListener = 'EventListener';
            var addEventListener = 'add'+EventListener;
            var removeEventListener = 'remove'+EventListener;
            var newScrollX, newScrollY;

            var dragged = [];
            var reset = function(i, el) {
                for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
                    el = dragged[i++];
                    el = el.container || el;
                    el[removeEventListener](mousedown, el.md, 0);
                    _window[removeEventListener](mouseup, el.mu, 0);
                    _window[removeEventListener](mousemove, el.mm, 0);
                }

                // cloning into array since HTMLCollection is updated dynamically
                dragged = [].slice.call(_document.getElementsByClassName('dragscroll'));
                for (i = 0; i < dragged.length;) {
                    (function(el, lastClientX, lastClientY, pushed, scroller, cont){
                        (cont = el.container || el)[addEventListener](
                            mousedown,
                            cont.md = function(e) {
                                if (!el.hasAttribute('nochilddrag') ||
                                    _document.elementFromPoint(
                                        e.pageX, e.pageY
                                    ) == cont
                                ) {
                                    pushed = 1;
                                    lastClientX = e.clientX;
                                    lastClientY = e.clientY;

                                    e.preventDefault();
                                }
                            }, 0
                        );

                        _window[addEventListener](
                            mouseup, cont.mu = function() {pushed = 0;}, 0
                        );

                        _window[addEventListener](
                            mousemove,
                            cont.mm = function(e) {
                                if (pushed) {
                                    (scroller = el.scroller||el).scrollLeft -=
                                        newScrollX = (- lastClientX + (lastClientX=e.clientX));
                                    scroller.scrollTop -=
                                        newScrollY = (- lastClientY + (lastClientY=e.clientY));
                                    if (el == _document.body) {
                                        (scroller = _document.documentElement).scrollLeft -= newScrollX;
                                        scroller.scrollTop -= newScrollY;
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 0
                        );
                     })(dragged[i++]);
                }
            }

              
            if (_document.readyState == 'complete') {
                reset();
            } else {
                _window[addEventListener]('load', reset, 0);
            }

            exports.reset = reset;
        }));
```

```css
* {
          box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        .pn-ProductNav_Wrapper {
          position: relative;
          padding: 0 11px;
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .pn-ProductNav {
          /* Make this scrollable when needed */
          overflow-x: auto;
          /* We don't want vertical scrolling */
          overflow-y: hidden;
          /* For WebKit implementations, provide inertia scrolling */
          -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
          /* We don't want internal inline elements to wrap */
          white-space: nowrap;
          /* If JS present, let's hide the default scrollbar */
          /* positioning context for advancers */
          position: relative;
          font-size: 0;
        }
        .js .pn-ProductNav {
          /* Make an auto-hiding scroller for the 3 people using a IE */
          -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
          /* Remove the default scrollbar for WebKit implementations */
        }
        .js .pn-ProductNav::-webkit-scrollbar {
          display: none;
        }

        .sticky-tabs-container {
          float: left;
          -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
          position: relative;
        }

        .sticky-tabs-container-no-transition {
          -webkit-transition: none;
          transition: none;
        }

        .sticky-tabs {
          text-decoration: none;
          color: #888;
          font-size: 1.2rem;
          font-family: -apple-system, sans-serif;
          display: -webkit-inline-box;
          display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
          display: inline-flex;
          -webkit-box-align: center;
              -ms-flex-align: center;
                  align-items: center;
          min-height: 44px;
          border: 1px solid transparent;
          padding: 0 11px;
        }
        .sticky-tabs + .sticky-tabs {
          border-left-color: #eee;
        }
        .sticky-tabs[aria-selected="true"] {
          color: #111;
        }

        .pn-Advancer {
          /* Reset the button */
          -webkit-appearance: none;
             -moz-appearance: none;
                  appearance: none;
          background: transparent;
          padding: 0;
          border: 0;
          /* Now style it as needed */
          position: absolute;
          top: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          /* Set the buttons invisible by default */
          opacity: 0;
          -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
          transition: opacity .3s;
        }
        .pn-Advancer:focus {
          outline: 0;
        }
        .pn-Advancer:hover {
          cursor: pointer;
        }

        .pn-Advancer_Left {
          left: 0;
        }
        [data-overflowing="both"] ~ .pn-Advancer_Left, [data-overflowing="left"] ~ .pn-Advancer_Left {
          opacity: 1;
        }

        .pn-Advancer_Right {
          right: 0;
        }
        [data-overflowing="both"] ~ .pn-Advancer_Right, [data-overflowing="right"] ~ .pn-Advancer_Right {
          opacity: 1;
        }

        .pn-Advancer_Icon {
          width: 20px;
          height: 44px;
          fill: #bbb;
        }

        .pn-ProductNav_Indicator {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
          height: 4px;
          width: 100px;
          background-color: transparent;
          -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
                  transform-origin: 0 0;
          -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: background-color .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out;
          transition: transform .2s ease-in-out, background-color .2s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-in-out;
        }

  #section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section4 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section5 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
  #section6 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
  #section7 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
  #section8 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
  #section9 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
  #section10 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}

  .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
  .sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<html class="js">
<title>Scroller for NGO page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<body>
<div class=" pn-ProductNav_Wrapper" id="navbar" style="">
<nav id="pnProductNav" class="pn-ProductNav dragscroll" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="1097" data-overflowing="both">
<div id="pnProductNavContents" class="sticky-tabs-container sticky-tabs-container-no-transition" style="transform: none;">
<a href="#section1" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="true">Overview</a>
<a href="#section2" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Team</a>
<a href="#section3" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Funds</a>
<a href="#section4" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#section5" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#section6" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#section7" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#section8" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#section9" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#section10" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<a href="#" class="sticky-tabs" aria-selected="false">Tab</a>
<span id="pnIndicator" class="pn-ProductNav_Indicator" style="transform: translateX(849.547px) scaleX(1.17859); background-color: rgb(0, 107, 73);"></span>
</div>
</nav>
<button id="pnAdvancerLeft" class="pn-Advancer pn-Advancer_Left" type="button">
<svg class="pn-Advancer_Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 551 1024"><path d="M445.44 38.183L-2.53 512l447.97 473.817 85.857-81.173-409.6-433.23v81.172l409.6-433.23L445.44 38.18z"></path></svg>
</button>
<button id="pnAdvancerRight" class="pn-Advancer pn-Advancer_Right" type="button">
<svg class="pn-Advancer_Icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 551 1024"><path d="M105.56 985.817L553.53 512 105.56 38.183l-85.857 81.173 409.6 433.23v-81.172l-409.6 433.23 85.856 81.174z"></path></svg>
</button>


</div>
<div id="section1" class="container-fluid content">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section4" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 4</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section5" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 5</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section6" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 6</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section7" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 7</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section8" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 8</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section9" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 9</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="section10" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Section 10</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
</body>
```

I want the tabs to scroll to tab (with active class) when user goes to the respective content (Anchor element).
I have tried many approaches but in vain.
And this being my initial stage into coding, kindly ignore if any code nomenclature is not followed.
The active tab needs a slider below the tab, showing the user that this is the active tab which he is On.
Any help to accomplish the required output is much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can write something on window onscroll to check the active section id or something like that.

Comment: Try to follow [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/)

Comment: can you be more specific? That would be helpful @Chilll007

Comment: @Partho63 . What I meant to ask in the question is, what if I have 10 tabs in the menu, and I want the menu bar to slide to active tab for the 10th tab too .

https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ant-financial Go through the above link and observe the menu bar section which shifts to active tab even after the horizontal overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:

```
Simple Material Design Inspired Tabs
```

following this link: https://codepen.io/jasonflaherty/pen/qOGgmp

```
Added Pagination Working arrows to it
```

https://codepen.io/mohan-aiyer/pen/RyaGza?editors=1010

Hope this helps.